# Object detection on webcam with tensorflow-js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to do object detection, using tensorflow-js, on the webcam stream

Below is my code:

```
let model;

var modelPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // Load the model.
      model = cocoSsd.load(); 
      $(".progress-bar").hide();

      if (model) {
        resolve("model loaded!");
      }
      else {
        reject(Error("problem loading model"));
      }
    });


const video = document.querySelector("#vid");

var camPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true })
          .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
          })
          .catch(function (err){
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
          });
      }
    });

// create function to detect objects in the image
const detection = (vid, mod) => {
        console.log("hi");
        mod.detect(vid).then(predictions => {
            //drawBBox(predictions); --> write function for this!
            console.log(predictions);
        });
        requestAnimationFrame(() => detection(vid, mod));
    };

Promise.all([modelPromise, camPromise])
      .then(values => detection(video, model))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The webcam stream is generated and displayed, but no predictions are being generated by cocoSsd; am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what is the error you have ?

Comment: Hi @edkeveked, the weird thing is, I'm not getting any errors in my console; however, something which I observed was: I tried to do a "console.log("hi"); in my detection function but "hi" isn't showing up in my console - is this some indication that my detection function isn't being called?

Comment: Can you please use stackblitz.com to demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: Have put my code on [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXwNbO) (the webpage hangs a little while the model and webcam loads so just hang tight); you can see that no predictions are being generated, nor does the console log the "hi" string which I put into the detection function as a test - appreciate your help, @edkeveked!